For a function $f(x)=x^3-x^2+x$ then limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{1}{(f^{-1}(x))^3+|f^{-1}(x)|}dx$ is?
For a function $f(x)=x^3-x^2+x$ then limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{1}{(f^{-1}(x))^3+|f^{-1}(x)|}dx$ is?
When I tried solving this integral I assumed that as the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ then the integral's limits both tend to infinity themselves collapsing the function's area to 0. I have no clue on how else to find the integral and I am assuming what we are supposed to do is solve the integral before and then put the limits on. How would any other approach work? Also I am stuck at finding the inverse of the function provided as it seems impossible to factorize the cubic.
I also tried to work this function by assuming that the area covered by the function about the x axis will be symmetrical in some sense to the y axis while taking the inverse but that approach failed.
PS:I am sorry if this question lacks any context.

next time please use \lim instead of lim

If $x>0$, then $(f^{-1}(x))^3+|f^{-1}(x)|=x+(f^{-1}(x))^2$

Given $f(x) = x^3 - x^2 + x$, we need to evaluate the limit:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{n}^{2n} \frac{1}{(f^{-1}(x))^3 + |f^{-1}(x)|} \, dx.
$$
For large $x$, $f(x) \approx x^3$, so $f^{-1}(x) \approx x^{1/3}$. The integrand simplifies to:
$$
\frac{1}{(f^{-1}(x))^3 + |f^{-1}(x)|} \approx \frac{1}{x + x^{1/3}} \approx \frac{1}{x}.
$$
Thus, the integral becomes:
$$
\int_{n}^{2n} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln\left(\frac{2n}{n}\right) = \ln(2).
$$
Therefore, the limit is:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{n}^{2n} \frac{1}{(f^{-1}(x))^3 + |f^{-1}(x)|} \, dx = \boxed{\ln(2)}.
$$
